# Node JS ProductProvider.getItem is Not Finding the Item in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am fairly new to JavaScript. I have been Googling and cannot find the answer.

I am trying to find a specific record in JSON. I come from a relation database background.

I have the following JSON:

```
Add to Cart tempProducts:[[{"inCart":false,"price":0,"_id":"5ec94e7649116e38802efb7d","title":"MyTitle","filePath":"/Uploads/Capture.JPG","createdAt":"2020-05-23T16:25:26.066Z","updatedAt":"2020-05-23T16:25:26.066Z","__v":0},{"inCart":false,"price":0,"_id":"5ec94ea049116e38802efb7e","title":"MyTitle2","filePath":"/Uploads/Capture.JPG","createdAt":"2020-05-23T16:26:08.892Z","updatedAt":"2020-05-23T16:26:08.892Z","__v":0},{"inCart":false,"price":0,"_id":"5ec94ed649116e38802efb80","title":"MyTitle3","filePath":"/Uploads/capture3.JPG","createdAt":"2020-05-23T16:27:02.309Z","updatedAt":"2020-05-23T16:27:02.309Z","__v":0}]]
```

I am looking for this id:

```
id: 5ec94ea049116e38802efb7e
```

You can see that this id exists in the JSON above.

And here is my code (this is the partial method):

```
addToCart = id => {
    console.log("id: " + id)
    let tempProducts = [this.state.products];
    console.log("Add to Cart tempProducts:" + JSON.stringify(tempProducts));

    console.log("Add to Cart Products:" + JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
    //const index = tempProducts.data.indexOf(item => item.id === id);
    console.log("index: " + index)
    const product = tempProducts[index];
```

The console log id prints the correct id.

Her is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Notice the index is -1.

Does anyone know why the getItem method would not be finding the matching id?

Edit: Removed stringify:

```
    console.log("id: " + id)
    let tempProducts = [this.state.products];
    //console.log("Add to Cart tempProducts:" + JSON.stringify(tempProducts));

    //console.log("Add to Cart Products:" + JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
    //const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(item => item.id === id);
    console.log("index: " + index)
    const product = tempProducts[index];
    console.log("tempProducts: " + tempProducts[index]);
```

The following screenshot is without the strigify:
[image]

Comment: The error you're making is creating a two-dimensional array here:
let tempProducts = [this.state.products];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the entire object based on the id:

```
const id = '5ec94ea049116e38802efb7e';

const product = this.state.products.find(product=>product._id === id);
```

Comment: thank you. You made me realize that I was missing the underscore in front of ID. Also, I did not really need to create tempProducts because I was setting it equal to this.state.products anyway. I think I am good to go now, but now I have more issues to fix  before I can verify. I am working on converting a tutorial from using a fixed json object in a file for data, to using MongoDB Atlas to store the product data.

Comment: As I mentioned above, by doing `let tempProducts = [this.state.products];` you were actually creating a nested array with `this.state.products` assigned to the first and only element of that array (products = [{...}, {...}, ...], tempProducts = [[{...}, {...}, ...]]).